# Sublime text 2 vintage mode disable ctrl+[

Tags: sublimetext2

I recently started using Vintage mode in Sublime Text 2. I also enable Ctrl Keys support by adding "vintage_ctrl_keys": true in my configuration file.

However, this affect my workflow because I am using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for indentation. Vintage mode basically remap <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> as escape.

Is there an easy way to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> mapping in vintage mode ? I am still using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for scrolling.

Comment: I tried using Ctrl+[ in vintage mode, and it does the indent/out-dent as usual. The vintage keymap doesn't use ctrl+[ either. Could you explain your requirement again please?

Comment: Hi Jamie, you need to add this in your Settings file "vintage_ctrl_keys": true ( http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html )

That will allow you to use ctrl+f and ctrl+b to scroll up and down.

Comment: So, are you saying you've found a solution after all?

Comment: Yeah, I just followed Riccardo's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable `vintage_ctrl_keys` and set key bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for page scroll:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "pages", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "pages", "forward": true} }
```